# mix spaces and tabs in python mode

Tags: whitespace-mode, indentation

Is it possible with whitespace-mode (or another mode) to only show mix spaces an tabs (in python mode) ?

Only highlight if:

- there is space before tab or tab before space
- there is space and `indent-tabs-mode` is `t`
- there is tabs and `indent-tabs-mode` is `nil`

obviously I don't want to see any character like `>>` or `.` for unmixed spaces or tabs.

Thanks for any helps